# Is there a way to override a CSS rule to essentially negate it?

Tags: css, css-cascade

If I have a `classic.css` file that I want to override (in this case it's from the Sphinx documentation used for Python: https://docs.python.org/2.7/_static/classic.css ) and essentially "undo" a rule, is there a way to do that?

In this case there are these rules:

```
div.sphinxsidebar h3 {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div.sphinxsidebar h4 {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

What I want to do is something like

```
div.sphinxsidebar h3,
div.sphinxsidebar h4
{
   font-family: [revert-to-auto];
   color: [revert-to-auto];
}
```

so I can specify the font-family and color in `body` and have it apply everywhere without having to use `!important`.

Just to clarify: I have my `custom.css` which starts with `@import(classic.css);` as per the Sphinx documentation, rather than the usual use of two `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` elements in the `<head>` section.

Comment: You can do `font-family: inherit;
   color: inherit;`.  but there is no way to undo in CSS.

Comment: You have to overwrite each declaration.  Usually, you can do something like `font-family: inherit` - but as the answer by @Caleb below points out, you need to also be sure the css loads in the proper order, AND that your selectors match exactly.

Comment: Aha, I think `inherit` might be what I had in mind. (couldn't remember what it was called) But it sounds like there are some subtleties.

Comment: Hmm. Chrome's CSS inspector doesn't seem to show what .css file actually causes the style when you have `inherit`.

Comment: Oh never mind, I accidentally put `inherit` for `body{}` as well. @Some Person could you post `inherit` as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS keyword `inherit` is usable for any property, and its function is to set the property to the value of the parent element.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use [`initial`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#initial) to revert to the [initial value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#initial-value) of that property

```css
div.sphinxsidebar h3,
div.sphinxsidebar h4
{
   font-family: initial;
   color: initial;
}
```

Or Cascade Level 4 introduces [`revert`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#valdef-all-revert), which rolls back the cascade to the user level

```css
div.sphinxsidebar h3,
div.sphinxsidebar h4
{
   font-family: revert;
   color: revert;
}
```

Comment: initial is almost never an appropriate value for font-family in author-level CSS - what that does is revert to the default family as specified in the user prefs (or some arbitrary browser default). This is one of the rarer cases where the "initial value" of a property is actually defined by the spec to be browser-dependent, and where the initial keyword actually does "revert to browser defaults". (initial for color is fine, since the initial value of color is currentcolor.) revert is OK as it takes "inherits by default" into account - in fact, this *exact use case* is what revert was made for.

Comment: Only problem is that revert is still very new and therefore not widely supported yet, and I wouldn't say initial is cross-browser ready just yet either. I'd make do with `font-family: inherit; color: currentcolor` - or, more broadly speaking, researching and manually applying the right value for each property.

Answer (score 0):

You want to include both CSS files in your `<head>` tag. The key is that you want your `custom.css` file to go underneath your `classic.css` file, like so:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="classic.css">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">
</head>
```

What this does is respect the 'cascading' portion of CSS. It sees the first rule in `classic.css` but then when it gets to `custom.css` it overwrites the rule it previously saw.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of exactly what values to specify in the custom.css declarations.

Comment: My bad, you're right. You'd want to use the [initial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) property, as mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: Oh -- sorry for not clarifying, that is what I am doing. (Actually in this case, Sphinx themes tell you to use `@import(classic.css);` )